# How to increase hibernate collection's processing speed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, collections

I need to optimise the performance of the code below.

```
List<CompanyCarRange> companyCarRanges = currentSession().createQuery(
            "from CompanyCarRange " +
                    "where idCompany=:idCompany")
            .setParameter("idCompany", id).list();
return companyCarRanges;
```

I found another way but performance is the same.

```
List<CompanyCarRange> companyCarRanges = new ArrayList<CompanyCarRange>();

    ScrollableResults scrollableResults = currentSession().createQuery(
            "from CompanyCarRange " +
                    "where idCompany=:idCompany")
            .setParameter("idCompany", id).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

    System.out.println(scrollableResults);
    while (scrollableResults.next()) {
        companyCarRanges.add( (CompanyCarRange) scrollableResults.get()[0]);
    }
return companyCarRanges;
```

For these two snippets, the execution time is 13 - 15 seconds for 500,000 rows.

```
   long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

   List<CompanyCarRange> companyCarRanges = new ArrayList<CompanyCarRange>();

    ScrollableResults scrollableResults = currentSession().createQuery(
            "from CompanyCarRange " +
                    "where idCompany=:idCompany")
            .setParameter("idCompany", id).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": time execution SQL");

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (scrollableResults.next()) {
        companyCarRanges.add( (CompanyCarRange) scrollableResults.get()[0] );
    }
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": time execution List");
    return companyCarRanges;
```

> 3601: time execution SQL, 9146: time execution List.
>   The while function's processing time is too long.

Comment: Please explain your database table and Entity class also. If the class/table contains joins or not, if yes, what is the type of joins and its handling...

Comment: Well generally speaking mysql isn´t the fastest database out there for bigger amounts of data. But even with a different Database-System the performance would probably just increase for about a second or something like that. There isn´t much you can do with the SQL-Statement either because it´s a pretty simple querry. The only way I could imagine a increase of performance would be by writting complex analyzing algorithms that resort the table based on row-usage. But then again that would take a lot of performance.

Comment: Yes i have 1 join. And this is my table model:
//..
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_car", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @BatchSize(size=100)
    private ServiceCar serviceCar;
// get / set methods

Comment: Is there an index on `idCompany`?

Comment: yes idCompany and idCar is indexing